# Automation of video recording on booting of raspberry pi3

Tags: python, bash, opencv, cron, raspberry-pi3

I have written a python code which contains some opencv code to play around with my webcam. I have attached it to raspi 3. I want that on startup(booting), it start recording video automatically..
I am using crontab for this.

> My Python code:

```
import cv

if __name__ == "__main__":
# find the webcam
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
capture1 = capture
# video recorder
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')  #cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc() does not exist
videoOut = cv2.VideoWriter('out1.avi', fourcc, 10.0, (640, 480))
videoOut1 = cv2.VideoWriter('out2.avi', fourcc, 10.0, (640, 480))
# record video
while (capture.isOpened() and capture1.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    ret1, frame1 = capture1.read()
    if ret:
        videoOut.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('Video Stream', frame)



    else:
        break
    if ret1:
        frame1 = cv2.flip(frame1,1)
        videoOut1.write(frame1)
        cv2.imshow('Video Stream1', frame1)

    else:
        break

    # Tiny Pause
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

capture1.release()
videoOut1.release()
capture.release()
videoOut.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

> Then I made a bash script which looks like this,

```
cd /
cd absolute path to my python file directory
sudo python cam22.py
cd /
```

cam22.py is the name of my python file

> Then I used contrab to run this bash script at runtime by writing

```
@reboot path to my bash file
```

After rebooting two avi files are generated in the same directory but the video is not recorded, the webcam doesn't runs, which however runs perfectly when I myself execute this bash file to run the python file.

As Suggested in comments, I've created a log file, it shows The error log shows (Video Stream:542): Gtk-Warning **: cannot open display:

Comment: Difficult to tell but if you want to log error, just write `@reboot path to my bash file >> logfile` to know what is actually happening.

Comment: Try removing interactions with screen and keyboard which may not be available to `cron` processes - `imshow()`, `waitkey()`...

Comment: @Bhavyanshu The error log shows (Video Stream:542): Gtk-Warning **: cannot open display:

Comment: That error message matches what I suggested. `cron` processes don't have a display - please try removing the `imshow()`, the `wait key()` and `destroyAllWindows()` and anything to do with a screen or terminal/keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Mark Setchell in the comments, it worked correctly after removing imshow(), waitkey().

Answer (score 0):

If two files are generated that means crontab works fine.
it also means that video not generated due to wrong format spelling .avi change it to .AVI and try once

```
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X')
videoOut = cv2.VideoWriter('output1.AVI', fourcc, 20, (640, 480), 1)
videoOut2 = cv2.VideoWriter('output2.AVI', fourcc, 20, (640, 480), 1)
```

Comment: hello sir, I think that file format should not be the problem because when I manually run this code, the video recording starts and it saves properly. bash file also operates perfectly, I have tested it. I have edited the question and added the error log. @Abhishek Soni

Comment: then i think this is something related to hardware just try to add some sleep at the start of the program and let me know if any progress

Comment: I've been doing this since yesterday, even tried for 2 minutes! @Abhishek Soni