# Raspberry python script with opencv won't execute at startup

Tags: linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, startup, opencv3.0

I have a Python 3 script on the Raspberry Pi 3 that uses opencv 3.4 to take pictures of from a Logitech webcamera and then upload it to dropbox. Code is adapted from pyimageserach.

So far the script works when I manually execute it from terminal or IDE.
The webcamera sometimes doesn't grab the picture, so it goes into a loop but eventually works. 
However, the code does nothing if I use one of the methods to automatically load it at startup.

```
    #system append
    import sys
    sys.path.append('/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/')
    sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/')

    import datetime
    import time
    import cv2
    import imutils
    import dropbox 
    #access dropbox
    client=dropbox.Dropbox("dropbox key not shown here")

    time.sleep(10)
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)   
    # Initialize the first frame
    firstFrame = None #keep the first fram clean to compare to all others

    #loop over the frames of the video
    while True:
        (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
         i = 1
         while grabbed != True:
               i = i+1
               print ("frame not grabbed")
               print ("Try AGAIN "+str(i)+" times in 15 seconds")
               camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
               time.sleep(15)
               (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()

         text = "Unoccupied Room"

    #resize the frame, convert it to grayscale, and blur it
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21,21), 0) 

    #if the first frame is None, initialize it
    if firstFrame is None:
         firstFrame = gray
         continue

     frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(firstFrame, gray) 
     thresh = cv2.threshold(frameDelta, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1] 

     # find contour of the image detected
     thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
     (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
     cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)



     # loop over the contours
     for c in cnts:
         # if the contour is too small, ignore it
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < 500:
              continue

        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        text = "Occupied Room"


     #draw the text and time stamp on the frame
     cv2.putText(frame, "Room Status: {}".format(text), (10, 20), 
     cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
     cv2.putText(frame, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A %d %B %Y 
     %I:%M:%S%p"), (10, frame.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 
     0.35, (0, 0, 255), 1)

     # show the frame and record if the user presses a key
     cv2.imshow("Security Feed", frame)
     cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)
     cv2.imshow("Frame Delta", frameDelta)
     key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

     # add my own stuff for occupied room
     if text == "Occupied Room":
     filename = 
     datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%Hh%Mm%Ss%f')+'.jpg'
     cv2.imwrite('./pictures/'+filename,frame)
     file_from = '/home/pi/Desktop/projects/pictures/'+filename
     file_to = '/pictures/'+filename

     try:
        with open (file_from, "rb") as file:
            client.files_upload(file.read(), file_to, mute=True)
        except ValueError:
             print ("Upload Failure")

        if key == ord("q"):
        # cleanup the camera and close any open window
            camera.release()
            del camera
            del frame
            del grabbed

            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Crons doesn't do anything, except telling me I had an env variable problem, which I appended.

init.d didn't work.
rc.local did not work.
I tried to use autostart lxde but that did not work
Bashrc briefly worked I wish it could work without having to log in.

I tried systemd and got the following errors

> Apr 12 01:24:50 raspberrypi python3.5[743]: Unable to init server:
>   Could not connect: Connection refused Apr 12 01:24:50 raspberrypi
>   python3.5[743]: cannot open display:  Apr 12 01:24:50 raspberrypi
>   systemd[1]: test.service: Main process exited, code=exited,
>   status=1/FAILURE Apr 12 01:24:50 raspberrypi systemd[1]: test.service:
>   Unit entered failed state. Apr 12 01:24:50 raspberrypi systemd[1]:
>   test.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

It seems like the webcamera will light up briefly and then disappear

At other times with systemd I get error with videoio error V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by opencv

Comment: Is `client=dropbox.Dropbox("dropbox key not shown here)` just a typo in the question or is in the real code ? Note the missing `"` at the end

Comment: yeah thats a typo sorry.  I edited it out last minute.  fixed it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45514571/2836621

Comment: Hey Mark I followed your advice.  Now I just get videoio error v4l1: pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by opencv.  Unable to stop the stream: device or resource busy.  The other error seems to be gone.  It's being loaded by systemd

Comment: A little update.  the v4l1 error seems to be gone.  Crontab and Systemd are WORKING now with opencv.  But the dropbox api is not uploading.  It is in the '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ folder that I appended.  There are no error messages.  It just doesnt upload.  what gives